# I am trying to understand the scope of the variable I am using in Perl

Tags: perl, scope

I am using this code below in Perl
What is the scope of the variable and what does it mean when you say $:: while declaring a variable?

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use Readonly;

my Readonly::Scalar $::variable_name => 'value';
```

Thanks in Advance!

Comment: `my Readonly::Scalar $::variable_name => 'value';` doesn't compile.

Answer (score 5):

From [perlfaq7](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlfaq7.html#How-can-I-access-a-dynamic-variable-while-a-similarly-named-lexical-is-in-scope%3f):

> If you know your package, you can just mention it explicitly, as in `$Some_Pack::var`. Note that the notation `$::var` is **not** the dynamic `$var` in the current package, but rather the one in the "main" package, as though you had written `$main::var`.

```
use vars '$var';
local $var = "global";
my    $var = "lexical";
print "lexical is $var\n";
print "global  is $main::var\n";
```

Answer (score 5):

`$::variable_name` is identical to `$main::variable_name`, and you should use the latter for clarity.

You meant either

```
Readonly::Scalar $main::variable_name => 'value';
```

which has global scope since `$main::variable_name` can be accessed from anywhere

or

```
Readonly::Scalar my $variable_name => 'value';
```

which has the same scope as a normal `my` declaration.

Since package variables are generally despised, the latter is preferable; although I realise that it may be useful to be able to access constant values globally